# Почему при вызове бокового меню, меня возвращает на верх сайта

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Реализовано боковое сменю следующим образом. Подскажите почему при вызове этого меню внизу страницы, меня переносит на верх

```js
$('.menu_btn').on('click', function(){
 $('.menu').toggleClass('menu_active');
 $('.menu_btn').toggleClass('btn_closed');
})
$('.fa-times').on('click', function(){
 $('.menu_btn').toggleClass('btn_active');
    $('.menu').toggleClass('menu_active');
})
```

```css
.menu{
 position: fixed;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 width:300px;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #000;
 transition: 1s all ease;
 transform: translateX(100%);
 z-index: 99;
}
.menu_active{
 transform: translateX(0);
}
.menu_closed{
 transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.btn_closed{
 transform: translateX(400%);
 transition: all 0s ease;
}
.btn_active{
 transform: translateY(0);
 transition: all 1.4s ease;
}
.menu_list{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: left;
 height: 50%;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin:40px 30px;
}
.menu_btn{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#FFF;
 width: 300px;
 background: #000;
 width: 100px;
 padding:  10px;
 display: flex;
 position: fixed;
 left: -170px;
 top:10px;
 z-index: 9;
 background: #000;
 justify-content: space-around;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
.menu_btn p{
 padding-top: 6px;
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#78D77C;
}

#navigation{
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#78D77C;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.fa-times{
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top:7px;   
    color:#FFF;
}
.fa-times:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.menu_list a{
    display: block;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    padding-top:20px;
}
#menu_descr{
    font-size: 15px;
    color:#414141;
    margin-top:50px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.soc_net i{
    color:#414141;
    margin-right:  20px;
    margin-left:3px;
}
.soc_net i:hover{
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
}
nav{
 position: relative;
 font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
      <a href="#" id="menu_btn" class="menu_btn"><p>MENU</p><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x "></i></a>
      <nav class="menu_list">
        <p id="navigation">navigation</p>
        <i id="fa-times" class="fas fa-times"></i>
                               <a href="#">Home</a>
                               <a href="#">About</a>
                               <a href="#">Services</a>
                               <a href="#">Works</a>
                               <a href="#">Cliens</a>
                               <a href="#">Contacts</a>
                               <p id="menu_descr">Perspiciatis hic praesentium nesciunt. Et neque a dolorum voluptatem porro iusto sequi veritatis libero enim. Iusto id suscipit veritatis neque reprehenderit.</p>
                               <div class="soc_net">
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram  fa-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook  fa-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fab fa-vk  fa-2x"></i>
                               </div>
      </nav>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что ты забыл сделать `preventDefault()`, а ссылка ссылается на `#`.

Comment: а не подскажите еще, почему первый раз кнопка скрывается и показывается нормально, а второй раз(не обновляя страницу) при нажатии она смещается влево

Comment: @АлександрПогребняк, неа, не смотрел код.

Answer (score 1):

потому что .menu_btn ссылка и при клике по умолчанию скролится к якорю. Нужно запретить.

```
$('.menu_btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.menu').toggleClass('menu_active');
    $('.menu_btn').toggleClass('btn_closed');
    return false;
})
```

Comment: а не подскажите еще, почему первый раз кнопка скрывается и показывается нормально, а второй раз(не обновляя страницу) при нажатии она смещается влево
UPD и стр обратно скролится вверх даже при наличии return false; (При использовании второй раз)

Comment: вероятно потому что у вас висит событие и на .menu_btn и на его дочернем элементе, куда попали при клике и откуда потом перешло по дереву. Оставьте на чем-нибудь одном и туда добавьте return false; .

Comment: не помогло, скорее всего неправильно сделано само меню,спасибо за уделенное время